# Delay button for creating an account

Tags: javascript

can you help me make when the second time they click the button it will wait 5 minutes to run the button again.

Like register an account. When you already create one account, you cant create another account. You must wait 5 minutes.

Comment: Yo have to do this serverside. If you run it on the client, reloading the page will restart the timer.

Comment: If It's not an extremely crucial task, then you can do it on the client-side using localStorage. Reloading the page won't clear data stored in localStorage.

Comment: Hi Sebastian. Im sorry but I still didnt understand how to implement it on my laravel project :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script>
var enableButton = function () {
   setInterval(()=> {
   if(Number(new Date().getTime()) -  Number(localStorage.getItem("time") >300000 )){
     document.getElementById("createAcc").disabled = false;
   } 
}, 3000)
}

function createAccount() {
   //your create account code goes here
   localStorage.setItem("time", new Date().getTime());
   document.getElementById("createAcc").disabled = true;
   enableButton();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="createAcc" onClick="createAccount()">Create Account</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will work if you don't care if they reload the page

Comment: In that case store the timestamp when user create the account in localStorage.
use setInterval instead of setTimeout, and you can compare the current snapshot of time with the snapshot of time stored in localStorage.
If it is >5mins clear the  interval.

Comment: Yet again the cache could be cleared. Don't get me wrong, your answer is correct and It's the best way to do it client side. But it won't be a "safe" way to achieve it.

Comment: Hi priston lewis I think for now i just follow your code with setInterval but I dont know how to edit in your old code you answered. Could you make it the update? Thank You :D

Comment: <button id="createAcc">Create Account</button>

enableButton() {
   setInterval(()=> {
   if((new Date().getTime()) -  Number(localStorage.getItem("time") >300000 );{
     document.getElementById("createAcc").disabled = false
   } 
}, 3000)
}

createAccount() {
   //your create account code goes here
   localStorage.setItem("time", new Date().getTime());
   document.getElementById("createAcc").disabled = true;
}